# How does bit shifting values in this GetHashCode method improve hashing?

Tags: c#, hash, bit-shift, gethashcode

I found two data types with hash code methods in a code base I'm working on, which I don't fully understand why they were chosen:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode() << 2;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode() << 2 ^ z.GetHashCode() >> 2;
}
```

How does the bit shifting operation make these hash values any better?

Comment: have you tried to do any research on the subject / google search on the following `C# does bit shifting operation make the hash values any better`?  I would start there first

Comment: You'd typically want to shift one or more (not all) of the values involved in a hash code so you can create a hash code that is more distributed.  For example in your first example if you didn't shift one of the values then the hash code for x=1,y=2 would be the same as x=2,y=1; but you want a different hash code to signify that those are actually two different values of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a `Point` data structure represented by a `x` and `y` variable. Without the bit shifting the value of hash code for `(1,0)` would be `1`, and the hash code for  `(0,1)` would also be `1`. Now do the same thing with the bit shifting, for `(1,0)` we get a hash code of `1`, but for `(0,1)` we now get a hash code of `4`

What the bit shifting provides is if you have the same inputs but in a different order you want to get different hash codes, that way `(1,0)` and `(0,1)` don't end up falling in to the same hash bucket and degrading your hashset/dictionary performance.

Normally you would do a much larger offset than just left shifting twice. Bitshifting also causes data to get truncated if dealing with hash codes near `Int32.MaxValue`. Here is the pattern I normally use

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = X;
        hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Y;
        hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Z;
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

(this is the default implementation that comes with Resharper's "Insert Comparison Method" feature. To add more fields you just keep doing `hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ XXXXXXX`)

By using `*` with `unchecked` instead of `<<` any value that is larger than `Int32.MaxValue` just overflows without error.

Comment: Also of note is that the implementation of `GetHashCode()` for `Tuple` (e.g. [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110))) is [based on](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,49b112811bc359fd) `(((h1 << 5) + h1) ^ h2);`